# Which meaning of "live" is used in TTL (Time To Live)?

Tags: ttl

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live

- Live as in: The show will go live on air this evening.
- or Live as in: I want to live in Paris.

For years I thought it was the first definition, but it just occurred to me that it makes more sense as the second.

Comment: As in "after given TTL I cease to exist".

Comment: Yeah. As in when creating a DNS record you set a TTL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the second. It's the amount of time that said packet has left to live, or alternatively the amount of time left until it dies, as opposed to the amount of time until it goes live.

Answer (score 1):

For [IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol) & DNS its the second definition. For example, for IP it indicates the amount of hops left that the packet can live before it will die. Each "hop" will reduce the TTL by 1 until it reaches 0(and dies) or its destination.